# Cannot fetch account details

Tags: dapps

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    //sets the state of the account as a part of the constructor.
console.log(accounts[0])
```

Id used the above code to display the account information of the user. I have tried with the Main Ethereum network and Ganache, using metamask. Unfortunately, it states the account is undefined. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that metamask is connected to Ganache? How have you started Ganache?

Comment: @goodvibration ya it is. I connected using the local rpc of Ganache

Comment: It however seems to be an issue with metamask. When I provide the rpc of ganache it gives out the address. Can you pls help me out with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute ethereum.enable() first, see:
https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs/Advanced_Concepts/Provider_API

Alternatively you could disable the privacy mode of metamask (in settings / Security & Privacy)
See https://medium.com/metamask/introducing-privacy-mode-42549d4870fa

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: No I havent. Will try.

Comment: Worked like a wonder.Thanks a tonne!!